# Regex that matches certain trailings of words with certain length?

Tags: java, regex

How can I write a regex that matches the "e" trailings of every word, exept the "e" trailings of words with 2 or 3 letters?

Example:

abcdeeee: Full match for "eeee"

more: Full match for "e"

pie: No match

me: No match

Comment: what regexps have you already tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: What environment are you executing your regex in? Both lookarounds and `\K` could solve your problem, but they aren't supported in every regex flavour.

Comment: Missing testcase: `meeeeeeee`

Comment: @mrzasa I have tried this: `\w{3,}.e*$` but this of course matches the word itself  that has an 'e' trailing and has more than 3 letters.

Comment: @Aaron I am using it in a `replaceAll` method in Java.

Comment: A lookbehind as in L3viathan's answer would work then. Java doesn't implement `\K`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookaround assertion:

```
e+(?<=\w{4})\b
```

This matches e characters if afterwards there have been 4 word characters before the final e. The `\b` makes sure it ends at a word boundary

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kvl1OU/1)**